# Include .sh script in Cocoa/Xcode output

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I'm using Xcode 3.2.6. I've added an sh script to my project. Is there a way to include that script in my project output when I build? I dragged it to the "Copy Files" build step thinking that would do it but no luck there.

Is there an official way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nm - I should have waited - noticed that my copy files build phase was going to an absolute folder, not the output folder of my program.